# Is there a strategy for solving a non-autonomous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm curious about techniques for solving a nonautonomous* system in the case of a non-linear differential equation. 
There's a simple example in my textbook (Hirsch, Smale, Devaney) where we obtain the following nonautonomous equation (after linearizing about the origin)

$$ x'(t) = x + y_0^2 e^{-2 t}$$

In this case, we simply guess a particular solution (which is obvious from the given equation) and everything follows through in a straightforward manner.  In a paper I'm working through I have an equation that looks something like

$$X'(t) = \frac{t}{6} - \frac{(a + X)^2}{t^2},$$

and I'm not sure what strategies I should have at my disposal here.  The literature on non-autonomous non-linear systems seems to be rather scarce from the bit of googling I've done.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

*By non-autonomous I simply mean there is a $t$ hanging around on the right-side of the equation.

Comment: First of all, your equation is linear. Second, it is even one of the form $y' + p(x) y = q(x)$ for which there is a standard solution using a multiplier. I don't see what makes you think your equation is so special, unless you made some mistake in writing it down?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes, I do apologise for the post.  The $\frac{a + X}{t}$ term should be squared (corrected now).  Though, I didn't intend for that equation to be the focus of the post.  I'm mainly just curious about strategies for solving non-autonomous non-linear equations in general. cheers

Comment: Thank you for editing it. It makes more sense now.

Comment: If you look at the usual proof of existence in ODE textbooks for first-order nonlinear equations, there's an approach via fixed point of a mapping defined by taking an integral in the neighborhood of an initial point.  To show the mapping is a contraction, and therefore has a fixed point, some strong continuity assumptions on the integrand are needed.  In your case there's a singularity at t=0, so you would need to work "away" from that point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=a+X$ ,

Then $y'=X'$

$\therefore y'=\dfrac{t}{6}-\dfrac{y^2}{t^2}$

Let $y=\dfrac{t^2u'}{u}$ ,

Then $y'=\dfrac{t^2u''}{u}+\dfrac{2tu'}{u}-\dfrac{t^2(u')^2}{u^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{t^2u''}{u}+\dfrac{2tu'}{u}-\dfrac{t^2(u')^2}{u^2}=\dfrac{t}{6}-\dfrac{t^2(u')^2}{u^2}$

$\dfrac{t^2u''}{u}+\dfrac{2tu'}{u}-\dfrac{t}{6}=0$

$6tu''+12u'-u=0$